# Does it make sense to memoize a toggle function with useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm following an *Advanced React Patterns with Hooks* online course and there's this early example in which they create an Expandable component (say the classic accordion or collapsible panels) with the following API:

```html
<Expandable>
    <Expandable.Header>This is the header</Expandable.Header>
    <Expandable.Body>This is the content</Expandable.Body>
</Expandable>
```

And they're using Context to pass the state `expanded` to Expandable's children. So far so good:

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

const ExpandableContext = createContext()
const { Provider } = ExpandableContext

const Expandable = ({children}) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)
  const toggle = setExpanded(prevExpanded => !prevExpanded)
  return <Provider>{children}</Provider>
}

export default Expandable
```

But then they say:

> `toggle` acts as a callback function and it’ll eventually be invoked by `Expandable.Header`. **Let’s prevent any future performance issues by memoizing the callback**

```js
const toggle = useCallback(
    () => setExpanded(prevExpanded => !prevExpanded),
    []
)
```

This confuses me because according to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) *`useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.* But toggle doesn't have any dependencies, and still it produces a different result (setting `expanded` state to `true` or `false` alternatively) every time.

So, what's the point of this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the state in `Expandable` component will be updated, `Expandable` component will re-render. This will cause the `toggle` function to be re-created.

To prevent this, it is wrapped in `useCallback` hook so that `toggle` function is not recreated unnecessarily across re-renders.

`useCallback` hook is used to memoize callbacks that are passed as props to child components. This can help avoid unnecessary execution of `useEffect` hook or any other code that depends on referential identity of the callback function passed as a prop from the parent component.

Comment: I see... So, _memoizing_ is more about keeping the function's identity stable between re-renders than caching outputs for given inputs, right?

Comment: Yes. For memoizing a value, `useMemo` hook is used.